# DRY fields in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I know about using inheritance and abstract models in reusing common fields in different models.

I'd like to know if the following approach is possible instead of inheritance and mixins.

```
from django.db import models

common_modified_by = models.CharField()


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    modified_by = common_modified_by


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    modified_by = common_modified_by
```

Will the above code work? Why or why not?

Comment: I'm not sure since those are the same instance.  Why not: `common_modified_by = lambda : model.CharField()`, then invoked like `modified_by = common_modified_by`.  This way both `Author` and `Book` would get a unique instance of `models.CharField` instead of both having a reference to the same `models.CharField`.

Comment: Why would sharing the same `CharField` instance not work?

Comment: Not sure.  You're welcome to give it a try, but hiding the creation of the instance behind a function is guaranteed to work.

Comment: This will work as-is (although you need to add `max_length=` to the field) model fields are just descriptors and you can add the same descriptor to multiple classes. Beware that if a user accesses the field via the `_meta` API then the same instance will be returned for each model, this could cause some issues if a user ever messes around with the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with reusing the same field in multiple models is that the `model` attribute of the field will be set to the last model where the field is defined

```
from django.db import models

common_modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    modified_by = common_modified_by


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    modified_by = common_modified_by
```

The field now has `Book` as it's `model` even when you get the field from the `Author` model. This can be problematic

```
>>>  Book._meta.get_field('modified_by').model
<class 'foo.models.Book'>
>>>  Author._meta.get_field('modified_by').model
<class 'foo.models.Book'>
```

One issue could be using the field as the target of a foreign key [`django.db.models.fields.related`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4122d9d3f1983eea612f236e941d937bd8589a0d/django/db/models/fields/related.py) seems to use this `model` attribute quite a lot

[It's also used when generating subqueries](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7acef095d73322f45dcceb99afa1a4e50b520479/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py#L84)

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I'm looking for.